# Troubles with "Connect to Server" option

Tags: server, ssh

I am using Ubuntu 14.04; the "connect to server" option has changed in the last few years from something like this

[image]

to something like this

[image]

Since I don't really know anything about servers or whatsoever I need some help to convert this few inputs to the corresponding one that I need to type in the second "connect to server" configuration:

- Server: abcd:1234 (I gues 1234 is the port)
- Type: ssh
- Folder: /home/myfolder
- Username utente: myname
- Password:  mypassword

(Name and numbers are just random for the sake of understanding)

**What do I have to type in the "server address" box?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

ssh://abcd:1234/home/myfolder

You will be asked for a username and a password.